# How to get background color of EditText on android

Tags: android, android-edittext, drawable

I would like to get color of EditText, I could set it by setBackgroundColor, but there is not getBackgroundColor function

I found this

```
EditText edtxt;
edtxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
PaintDrawable drawable;
Log.d(TAG,"1");
drawable = (PaintDrawable)edtxt.getBackground();
if(drawable.getPaint().getColor()==(int)Color.GREEN).........
Log.d(TAG,"2");
```

but its not working and crashing

```
05-29 19:20:27.526: E/AndroidRuntime(20255): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.PaintDrawable
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 4):

This should work for API level 11 and up

```
ColorDrawable drawable = (ColorDrawable)edtxt.getBackground();
if(drawable.getColor()==(int)Color.GREEN)
System.out.println("It's Green");
```

If you want it to wok on earlier APIs, I would suggest using a Custom `EditText` and overriding the `setBackgroundColor(int color)` method.

```
public class NewEditText extends EditText {
private int color;
public NewEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public NewEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public NewEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}   


@Override
public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.color=color;
    super.setBackgroundColor(color);
}

public int getBackgroundColor() {

    return color;
}
}
```

Now in the Layout use:

```
<com.aneesh.mypackage.NewEditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/customview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and your Activity Code will change to

```
NewEditText custView = (NewEditText)findViewById(R.id.customview);
custView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
if(custView.getBackgroundColor()==(int)Color.GREEN)
  System.out.println("It's green");
```

Comment: I try it before, but: The method getColor() is undefined for the type ColorDrawable

Comment: Oh yes that method is available only from API 11(HoneyComb and up).  [getColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html#getColor%28%29)

Comment: StateListDrawable cannot be cast to ColorDrawable exception occurs. This answer does not work.

Comment: Doesn't work with API 25. `EditText.getBackground()` returns an instance of [InsetDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the color in runtime it could be better to save some kind of flag (boolean for example) to know which is the background color of the edit text.

Comment: I already think about it, too lazy to declare flags and will make tonns of code bypass it.